# code is not working on IE8 and Mozilla Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, browser, gson

I am developing a web application using JSP & Servlet.

I am using  **gson2.2.2**

When i run the following code on `google chrome 24.0.1312.57 m` it is working fine, but when i try to run the same code on `IE8` and on `Mozilla Firefox 3.6.13` then the same code is not filling the `combobox`.

**HTML:**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Testing Browser</title>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() { 
        alert('in');
        //fill Salutation
        var $ul = $(SALUTATION);
        $.get('MyServlet?action=cmbSALUTATION', function(responseJson) {
            $.each(responseJson, function(index, item) {
                $('<option>').text(item).appendTo($ul);
            });
        });
    });
</script>
</head>

<body>
   <table>
       <tbody>
          <tr>
              <td>Salutation</td>
              <td><select name="SALUTATION" id="SALUTATION"> </select></td>
          </tr>
       </tbody>
   </table>
</body>
</html>
```

**Servlet:**

```
//COMBOBOX - Get the data for column SALUTATION
        if(request.getParameter("action")!=null)
        if(request.getParameter("action").equalsIgnoreCase("cmbSALUTATION"))
        {
            String s2[][] = select.getData("select TITLE_ID from CRM_TITLE");
            List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
            for(int i=0;i<s2.length;i++)
            {
                list.add(s2[i][0]);
            }
            String json = new Gson().toJson(list);
            response.setContentType("application/json");
            response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
            response.getWriter().write(json);
        }
```

Please let me know if i am missing something..

Thanks in advance....

Comment: A servlet uses this JSP to write HTML with Javascript that calls another servlet to get stuff which you then put into the HTML. Why can't the original servlet get the info needed for you to use a c:forEach in this JSP, instead of complicating your life this way?

Comment: @DownVoters reason for downvoting will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
 var $ul = $('#SALUTATION'); // <----id selector
    $.get('MyServlet?action=cmbSALUTATION', function(responseJson) {
        $.each(responseJson, function(index, item) {
            $('<option />').text(item).val(index).appendTo($ul);
        });  //----^^^^^^-----------------------------try with this
    });
```

Comment: thanks for answer, but this still only works on chrome and not on IE and Mozilla

Comment: check that if ie and mozilla has javascript enabled.

Comment: i checked it, mozilla has javascript enabled

Answer (score 0):

Try This Link [jQuery Function](http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/6673). Most of the Jquery Plug-ins are not supported by in IEs.
Otherwise test the JavaScript lint Errors. [JavaScript Online lint Error](http://www.javascriptlint.com/online_lint.php)

Comment: thanks for answer, i have test javascript lint errors using [JavaScript Online lint Error](http://www.javascriptlint.com/online_lint.php) but there are no errors in javascript